# Rails - ActiveRecord - Trigger mail on change of a field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on a functionality where i need to trigger a mail to a list of users once the record field value has been updated successfully.

For eg: I have a Blog model which has published attribute(represents a column in my database table) with default value as false. When the user published the blog, the field value will become true and i need to send some mails.

1. Which is the best way of doing it?
2. If I can use after_update callback, how will i get to know that published column has been updated during the last update call?
3. Is there a way to access the old value of the published attribute after the update?

Any help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1) might be a little subjective but I'll answer that along with 2)
ActiveRecord provides methods to indicate whether an attribute has changed.  You can use the attribute name + `_changed?`.  E.g. If your model has a `name` attribute, then it will also respond to `#name_changed?`  Here is one way you can send email only if an attribute has been changed:

```
class MyModel
  after_update :send_email, :if => :column_name_changed?

  def send_email
    # Send email here
  end
end
```

3) The old attribute value can be accessed by appending `_was`.  E.g. `#name_was` will return the old value of the name field.

**UPDATE:**

To send an email only the first time that a field is switched from false to true you will need to add another field to your database, such as `email_sent`.  Since the condition for the `send_email` callback became more complex, I moved it into the callback itself.  After the email is sent, set the `email_sent` field to true, so that no further emails are delivered.

```
class MyModel
  after_update :send_email

  def send_email
    if column_name_changed? && !email_sent?
      # Send email here
      update_attribute :email_sent, true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a way to trigger mail only once( the first time field value changes from false to true)?

Comment: Won't it go in infinite loop if you will give update again in the block.

Comment: @ShilpiAgrawal The condition `if column_name_changed? && !email_sent?` should prevent the infinite loop. Now looking at this answer more than 4 years after originally posting, I would recommend using [`update_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) rather than `update_attribute` (unless it was necessary to run validations when setting `email_sent` to `true`).